# Unexpected end of line - dos2unix won't fix it

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail
set -u

se () { sed -n 's/\s*r('"$1"').*|r| =\s\+//p'}

### gets the number of cell opt steps
exec 0<"DEMLIR.out"
while read -r line
 do
 gawk 'BEGIN{FS="OPTIMIZATION STEP:"} {print $2}' | tr -s " "
 done>results

 sed -i '/^$/d' results
 #sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' results

 step=$(tail -n 1 results)
 echo "${step}"

### gets the number of steps in each geo_opt output
 for i in $(seq 1 $step)
 do
 exec 0<"DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-$i.out"
 while read -r line
 do
 gawk 'BEGIN{FS="OPTIMIZATION STEP:"} {print $2}' | tr -s " "
 done>results_geo_$i

 sed -i '/^$/d' results_geo_$i

 step_geo=$(tail -n 1 results_geo_$i)
 echo "${step_geo}"

### goes through each line in distance.out and prints distances to array 
 exec 0<"DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-$i-distance-1.coordLog"
 while read -r line
 do
 for j in $(seq 0 $step_geo)
 do
 "$line" | se
 paste -d' ' <(printf '%s\n' $j) <(se 1,5) <(se 2,5) <(se 2,8)

 done
 done

 done>DEMLIR_task.txt
```

I try to run this program but I keep getting the `unexpected end of line error`on line 53. I saw that there are already answers for this problem but when I try `dos2unix`it says 
`dos2unix: converting file script_step.sh to Unix format...`
but that's it. And when I run the code again it won't work.

I am expecting some errors at the last for loop, so if you see some you can also point them out. But if they are not related to the original problem then you can just ignore them.

Comment: `echo >> script_step.sh`?

Comment: @Cyrus won't it add an extra line at the end?

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net

Comment: `se` isn't defined properly: `se () { sed -n '...'; }`. `}` isn't special if it isn't a *word* by itself; as is, it' just part of the argument to `sed`, and the parser never sees the end of the function definition.

Comment: @beliz: Yes, it does. But I was probably on the wrong track.

Comment: Yes I also realised that.. It should have been in the next line.. Thanks @chepner

Comment: Your script does not call `dos2unix`.

Comment: @jww Well, I fixed the problem with the function and it is not giving `unexpected end of line` error anymore

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
se () { sed -n 's/\s*r('"$1"').*|r| =\s\+//p'}
```

You need a semicolon or newline before the `}`. Otherwise, it's treated as part of the `sed` argument.